# Display album art in GridGView and show the list of song files each album on click of each album art (GridView item)

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am currently working on a uwp music player and I want to display each album art from music library on launch of the application in GridView  and then on click of each album art the list of song files for that album is displayed on a new page in uwp c#

Comment: So... what have you tried already?

Comment: I am able to display the song files and the thumbnails all together but i want to display only album arts and then on click of any of them then it displays a list of song files for that album

Comment: Please add code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create the `Album` class that included a `ObservableCollection` of `Song`.

For example:

```
class Album
{
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
public class Song
{
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

You can set the `Album` to a `ObservableCollection` then you can set the collection to the `ItemsSource` of the `GridView`.

To get the current selected `Album`, we can add `GridView.SelectionChanged` event. In the event we can use `GridView.SelectedIndex` to get the index of the `Album` collection.

To send the `Album` to a new page, we can use [`Navigate(Type sourcePageType, object parameter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Methods_) method. It causes the Frame to load content represented by the specified Page, also passing a parameter to be interpreted by the target of the navigation. In the new page, we should be able to override `OnNavigatedTo` that we can get the `Album` by `NavigationEventArgs.Parameter`.